# Cannot resolve symbol MavenDeployment on gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, maven-plugin

I've an app and a library that supports the app, everything is fine ( I can compile the app with the library dependency

And the `build.gradle` file is always with this error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol MavenDeployment on gradle
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue? Also can you post your code and not a picture of your code?

Comment: I am too seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I no longer have this issue since Android Studio 2.0

Comment: I'm on Android 3.2 and I'm just having this issue :D but I'm trying to import a project written 3 years ago from github, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Making gradle version as 3.1.0 in the project level **build.gradle** fixed it.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```